# How to change the background video from the video clip editor when changed?

Tags: movie-clip-editor

[image]hello, I recently had several videos filmed in order to embed an object inside.  but the first time it didn't work so I filmed another one and now it works, however, now when I render I end up with well the object I want but the wrong video in  back.  however I did click on "set as background".  how can i fix it because it's for at school project and i need it the faster possible.  Thanks a lot [image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understood, but ... Select Camera go to Properties Editor > Camera Properties > Background Images and change what ever file you need, but just to admit its only for viewport preview purpose to get it combined in final render you have to use Compositor or add a Plane with video texture infront of camera in 3Dview.

Comment: [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org) Please don't post photos of your monitor, these are hard to diagnose because we can't tell if we are looking at a physical issue like reflection or smudge, a hardware issue like a malfunctioning display, a software level issue, or an or actual artifact or issue with the model itself.